# How to move PAM from DR to primary machine without any downtime?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, failovercluster

My environment is :
Primary site : 2 MBX  and 2 CAS   -- fsw \srv01\dag
DR Site :  1 MBX and 1 CAS  --alternate fsw  \srvdr1\dag
my question is  : I want to move primary  mailbox  node  (pr-mbx-01 )without downtime. is it possible ?

It shows WitnessShare InUse: PRIMARY
Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup -Status | fl :

Group                Node            Status

---

Cluster Group        DR-mbx-01      Partially Online
Available Storage    PR-MBX-02      Offline

Answer (score 0):

You could run below command to move PrimaryActiveManager to another server:

`Get-ClusterGroup “Cluster Group” | Move-ClusterGroup –Node <Other DAG Member>`

Here's a similar thread for your reference: [How to move Primary Active Manager role - Exchange 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/363142/how-to-move-primary-active-manager-role-exchange-2.html)

The [thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2357976-how-to-move-pam-from-dr-to-primary-machine-without-any-downtime?page=1#entry-9462115) seems to the same issue as yours.